# Kotlin Coroutines how to achieve to call api in right way

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Hey I want to call **api** from **object** class. I am new in Coroutines. I tried some code, but i am not sure is it correct way of doing it or not.

1. Inside **LoginHelper** there is function called **logout** have more that one function. I want to excute api call first. then i want to excute other function inside logout.
2. In **Mainactivity** I am calling **LoginHelper.logout** it will finish then i need to excute other line. But i don't want to make suspend function because it's using other place as well.

**Also i got a errorProcess:**

```
com.dimen.app, PID: 12496
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
```

**Session.kt**

```
interface Session{
    @DELETE("/session/delete")
    fun deleteSession(): Call<Void>
}
```

**SessionRepository.kt**

```
suspend fun deleteSession(): RequestResult<Void> {
        return apiCall(api.deleteSession())
}
```

RequestResult is a [Sealed Class](https://medium.com/codex/kotlin-sealed-classes-for-better-handling-of-api-response-6aa1fbd23c76)

```
sealed class RequestResult<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(): RequestResult<T>
    data class Error(): RequestResult<Nothing>()
    fun result(success: (data: T?) -> Unit),error: (error: Error) -> Unit)
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private fun setupLogout() {
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener {
        LoginHelper.logout() // need to wait untill this finish
        // more logic here....
    }
}
```

**LoginHelper.kt**

```
object LoginHelper {

    fun logout() {
        logD("logout")
        deleteSession() // need to wait untill this finish and then excute more function....
    } 

    private fun deleteSession() {
       runBlocking{
        apiCall.deleteSession().execute()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `apiCall.deleteSession(it)` return?

Comment: Only to excute it returns Void

Comment: But what type is it? Does it synchronously do a long task? Is `getToken()` or `deleteSession()` a suspend function?

Comment: @Tenfour04 `getToken` is normal function it returns string. `deleteSession()` is api call and return RequestResult<Void> it a sealed class. [Sealed Class](https://medium.com/codex/kotlin-sealed-classes-for-better-handling-of-api-response-6aa1fbd23c76)

Comment: So `apiCall.deleteSession()` starts an asynchronous request and returns immediately? If that's the case, you don't need coroutines at all for any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `runBlocking` in an Android app unless you know exactly what you're doing. It's the wrong choice 99% of the time because it defeats the purpose of using coroutines. Blocking means the current thread waits for the coroutine to run its asynchronous code. But you cannot block the main thread because that freezes the UI.

Since your LoginHelper is an `object` or singleton, it needs its own CoroutineScope if it's going to launch coroutines.

You can make `deleteSession()` a suspend function so it can call the `api.deleteSession()` suspend function.

You can make `logout()` launch a coroutine to sequentially delete the session and subsequently perform other tasks. And you can make it return the launched Job so other classes can choose whether or not to simply start the logout, or to start and wait for the logout in a coroutine.

```
object LoginHelper {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + CoroutineName("LoginHelper"))

    fun logout(): Job = scope.launch {
        logD("logout")
        deleteSession()
        // .... more functions that happen after deleteSession() is complete
    }

    private suspend fun deleteSession() {
        Tokenclass.getToken()?.let {
            logE("token ::-> $it")
            apiCall.deleteSession(it).execute()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the outside class to be able to wait for the `logout` to complete, it can call `join()` on the returned Job in its own coroutine, for example:

```
logoutButton.setOnClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        LoginHelper.logout().join()
        // more logic here....
    }
}
```

If you don't need to wait for it in the activity, you don't need to start a coroutine, and you don't need to call `join()`.

Comment: can you please see the image. it's giving error on `logout` function. I don't want to create `logout` function to **suspend** it will effect other place

Comment: you added `// .... more functions. These will probably occur before Executor is done.` this line. If i want to excute first `deleteSession` function then after it will on other function. How can we achieve this.

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 i updated the question fully what i am using. can you please check that. What i am trying to do and what return type `deleteSession()`.

Comment: One little doubt @Tanfour04 what's the d/w `SupervisorJob` and `Dispatchers.IO/MAIN?DEFAULT`.

Comment: A CoroutineScope that is used for multiple different coroutines should have a SupervisorJob as its context so if any of the launched coroutines fails, it won't cancel other coroutines that were launched from that scope. Since I didn't specify a dispatcher, it will use Dispatchers.Default, which is appropriate here, because this class does not work with UI components, so it doesn't need to do anything on the Main dispatcher.

Comment: Great Stuff @Tenfour04 Thanks a million once again